# Can a tyre of r14 fir into a wheel of r14

Tags: tires

I ve rim of r13.
Is it possible for wheel size r14 to fit into this ..I don't Want to change the wheels

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking, please put some effort into your question. Do you have R13 wheels and want to fit R14 tyres on it? No, that's not possible. Wheel outer diameter and tyre inner diameter must match.

Answer (score 1):

The number immediately following the R in tyre size information denotes the diameter of the wheel which that tyre is designed to be mounted upon.  This is quotes in inches and the beads of the tyres (i.e. the bits that seal against the rim) are made to be the appropriate diameter.

You must ensure that your wheel diameter and tyre diameter number match exactly or the tyre will not mount upon the rim.